# Lucene ToChildBlockJoinQuery

Tags: join, lucene

I'm trying to search using lucene - toChildBlockJoinQuery. I have a parent document (has fields A, B,C and a DocType:"parent" filter) and a set of child documents for each parent(each child doc has fields D, E) and indexed in order - set of child docs and then parent doc.

I'm trying to query docs that has B:"somevalue" AND (D:"value1" or D:"value2" or D:"value3" ..)

I'm using ToChildBlockJoinQuery to filter docs by parentfield value and then add query of childfield values and searching the index.

Find my code below:

```
Query parentFilter = new TermQuery(new Term("DocumentType","parent"));
Filter parent= new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(parentFilter));
TermQuery B= new TermQuery(new Term("B",somevalue));
parentQuery.add(B, Occur.MUST);
ToChildBlockJoinQuery blockJoinQuery = new ToChildBlockJoinQuery(parentQuery , filter, false);

BooleanQuery D= new BooleanQuery();
for(int m=0; m< dValues.length; m++){
D.add( new TermQuery(new Term("D", dValues[m])), Occur.SHOULD);
}
BooleanQuery innerQuery = new BooleanQuery();
innerQuery.add(blockJoinQuery,Occur.MUST);
innerQuery.add(D,Occur.MUST);

TopDocs tD = this.searcher.search(innerQuery, 10);   // or
TopDocs tD = this.searcher.search(blockJoinQuery, 10);
```

both gives me 0 results. I'm able to fetch all the indexed docs using a different ToParentBlockJoinQuery and changing the clause to occur.SHOULD. I can see that the matching docs are there in the generic results. However, I'm not able to fetch any results if I use the above query.

Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong with the ToChildBlockJoinQuery. Any help is appreciated!

//Edited this post// 
Here is how I index the docs:

```
public void indexParentAndChildDoc(String A, String B, String C){
/**
*This part has code to get values A, B and C
**/
for (int i = 0; i <elementS.length; i++){

    String D, E1, E2 = null;
    D = //code to get value for D
    E1 = //code to get value for E1;
    E2 = //code to get value for E2;
documents.add(createChildDocs(D,E1, E2));
}

documents.add(createParentDoc(A, B, C));
if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND){
writer.addDocuments(documents);
}
documents.clear();
}

private Document createParentDoc(String A, String B, String C){ 
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new Field("A", A, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
document.add(new Field("B", B, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
document.add(new Field("C", C, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
document.add(new Field("DocumentType", "parent", TextField.TYPE_NOT_STORED));
return document;
}

private Document createChildDocs(String D, String E1 String E2) {

Document document = new Document();
document.add(new Field("D", D, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
    document.add(new Field("E", E1+":"+E2, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
    return document;
}

//This code indexes parent docs along with the related child docs
String[] elementS = //child objects of this parent
indexParentAndChildDoc("valueA", "somevalue", "valueC");
```

search on this indexed doc providing the above code doesn’t fetch any results.

Comment: Can you provide us with a full test case that reproduces the issue (including indexing code)?

Comment: I'm sorry I'll be unable to provide the details of the code as this is a current research project I'm working on. However, I'm providing a replica of the actual code with the paramter/values I have specified above. I'd really appreciate your thoughts on this.